# How can I sum the neighbor array and break with some greater than condition in python?

Tags: python, arrays

`arrangebox = np.array([[1, 0], [2, 500], [3, 500], [4, 0], [5, 0], [6, 0], [7, 0], [8, 0], [9, 0], [10, 0], [11, 0], [12, 0], [13, 0], [14, 1500], [15, 0], [16, 0], [17, 0], [18, 0]])`

For my array, I try to sum each pair of array starting with array 1 and 2 or 0+500=500,then keep this value to sum with array 3 to give 500+500=1,000.... However, the condition is that if sum of arrangebox is equal or grater than 1,500, everything then must stop and print the answer. My target in this problem is to keep only array ([  2,  500],[  3,  500]) and the answer 1,000 is because it rejects sum on [14, 1500] that make sum value equal to 2,500 that more than 1,500.

For my attempt has a wrong answer (1,500):

```
for i in range (17):
    s = arrangebox[i][1]+arrangebox[i+1][1]
    if s>= 1500:
       break
    i=i+1
```

What would you recommend me? Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you start by fixing your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is very close to computing the sum of an array/list. Instead of writing `s = arrangebox[0][i][1]+arrangebox[0][i+1][1]`, you should initialize `s` to 0 before the `for` loop, then write `s += arrangebox[0][i][1]`.

Also, I think you misunderstood the use of `for` loops, it is already increasing `i` everytime it executes what is inside the loop.

Finally, are you sure you need an array in this situation? And if the answer is yes, consider only using the indexation of the array, like so:

```
arrangebox = np.array([0, 500, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1500, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

This way, you can write your test like so:

```
s = 0
for i in range(len(arrangebox):
    if s>= 1500:
       break
    s += arrangebox[i]
```

Note that using `range(len(arrangebox)` is way more versatile than using a specific numerical value, if you happen to have an array not the exact same size as the one you are using here.